# A fly in a cube

Tags: probability

I stumbled upon this problem:

Inside a cube, on a wall, rests a fly. At each step the fly selects a wall it is not currently on, with uniform probability, and flies there. What's the probability after 100 steps that the fly is on the same wall it started on? What's the probability after N steps?

I don't really know how to account for the fact that at each step the fly only as 5 possible choices, and consequent steps have different sets of possible walls where the fly may move to.

Comment: Floors and ceilings aren't "walls"

Comment: @trueblueanil I translated this problem, in the original text it's clear that all inside faces of the cube are possible landing spots... Anyway I don't think it really matters... You could rewrite the problem as: You have 6 boxes, in one of this boxes there is a ball, at each step you take the ball out of it's current box and place it in another, that you chose with uniform probability, what is the probability the ball is back in the starting box after 100 steps?

Comment: Hint: Number the "walls" $1$ through $6$. The *Pr* for going from any wall to *any* other wall is 1/5, and so it can return in one step to $1$ from any non $1$wall, *which simplifies the problem a lot*

Comment: @trueblueanil Yeah... it's not hard to find a recursive formula for the probability at the n-th step $Pr_n = \frac{1}{5}(1-Pr_{n-1})$, now I wonder how you can show that $Pr_n \to \frac{1}{6}$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Nevermind is actually pretty simple

Comment: Sorry, our timings don't match, so much delay ! I have answered your query both intuitively and algebraically. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting a rudimentary answer, but before that here is an intuitive observation:

**Approaching $\infty$ time, the starting place's influence will be waning to zero, and the fly tending towards having equal probabilty $\dfrac16$ of being on any surface, and $100$ steps may be large enough to just use the limiting solution.**

Let the fly start from the floor $(F)$ with the walls/ ceiling being $(W)$

After one step, the fly is on $W$ with Pr $= 1$

After two steps, the fly is on $F$ with Pr$=\frac15$, on $W$ with Pr = $1- \frac15$

After three steps, the fly is on $F$ with Pr$=\frac15(1-\frac15)= \frac15 - \frac1{25}$

After four steps, the fly is on $F$ with
Pr$= \frac15[1-(\frac15-\frac1{25} )] = \frac15 - \frac1{25}+ \frac1{125}$

You can see that this is a **GP** with $a = \frac15, r = -\frac15$
and you can use the GP formula to compute $F(100)$

---

**PS:**
In decimal form, [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B5%5E%28n-1%29%2B%28-1%29%5En%5D%2F%5B6*5%5E%28n-1%29%5D%2C+n+%3D+100) gives the result as $0.166667$